# Will I be able to import my Google Earth site files to a Surface 2 running Windows 8.1 RT

Tags: windows-rt, google-earth, surface-2

The guys at the Microsoft store have assured me that I will be able to transfer my Google Earth .kmz files successfully.  But I have seen posts online that say you can't import to Windows RT only to regular Windows on a laptop or desktop.  I really need my tablet to support Google Earth .kmz files.  If a Surface 2 won't work, what will?  Thanks for any input!

Comment: .kmz is basically just XML for Google Earth. Does Google Earth have an RT release (Available in Windows Store?)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't find any reference to an official RT release from Windows.  I HAVE found numerous references to free, unofficial downloads of an RT Version of Google Earth.  The sites look sketchy...so I am still not ready to invest in a Surface 2. Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

The short, all signs appear to point to "no".

Windows RT apps should only come from the Windows Store. [A Short search returns nothing.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=google+earth)

A Surface 2 Pro would support Google Earth and thus .KMZ files, but RT does not appear to have a Google Earth app.